# 'colocate_with', 'to_int32' occurs when integrating tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to analyze why such errors occur in my simple codes when using tensorflow and keras simultaneously

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,1))

hidden=Dense(neu, activation='sigmoid',
         kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=lamb, l2=lamb)) 
         (X) #colocate_with occurs
neural=Dense(1,
         kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=lamb, l2=lamb)) 
         (hidden)

output=X+X**2*neural
first_term=tf.gradients(tf.gradients(output,X),X)[0] #to_int32 occurs
```

Detailed warnings are

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   D:\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263:
>   `colocate_with` (`from tensorflow.python.framework.ops`) is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
>   Colocations handled automatically by placer.

and

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   D:\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066:
>   `to_int32` (`from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops`) is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use `tf.cast`
>   instead.

I think those are two separated problems. 
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Basically, those are just warning messages. They won't affect code execution.

Comment: Oh yes. I deleted last sentences

Comment: In this case those messages just warn about future changes in the API and suggest to switch to another function. In this case they are used internally, so you can ignore them

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you! :)